# Different possible semantic interpretation of a statement

Tags: compiler-construction

I have a question on an assignment that says to draw three different possible semantic interpretation of the statement:

> a = b;

I am unsure how to represent this. I know that it can be an identifier 'a' being assigned an identifier 'b', identifier 'a' being assigned a character 'b', and a comparison of the value of the two identifier. Is this correct? and how would I represent this.

Answer (score 2):

In the absence of a reference manual for a programming language, you can invent "reasonable" interpretations based on knowledge of programming languages in general.

On first look, yours are pretty reasonable.  Maybe.

Certainly assignment of one variable's content to another is one interpretation, and in fact this syntax is pretty common in current programming languages.

Comparison is one... well, except that it isn't clear what happens to the result of the compare.  Why would one compare two values... with no further action?   So I would probably reject this interpretation.  (There are many current languages [e.g., C, C++] that in fact will let you write this, and will compile this as a no-operation because nothing changes.  But this is pointlessly stupid, and considered mostly to be a defect of such languages).

Assignment of the letter "b" to the variable a... sort of.  Of course, if that's what it meant, how would one assign the content of variable b to the variable a?  So if you choose this interpretation, you have to assume the language cannot assign one variable to another... or, it has ugly syntax for doing such assignments.  Nobody designs a language like this on purpose in practice.  Generally one has special syntax for character literals, e.g., "b", to distinguish character constants from identifier names.

But, your guesses were reasonable.

[I have no idea what "how I would represent this" means].

Comment: Yeah I don't either. We are using Louden Programming Languages and Principle 3rd edition as the textbook and I'm having trouble finding an example.

Comment: If you have a "formal" textbook, perhaps it talks about formal semantics of language constructs?  In that case, "represent" would mean,  "write a formal semantic description of your interpretations".  If this is what you book is pushing, it should be pretty obvious with big chapters on the topic.  Otherwise I'm back to "I don't know".

Comment: I found it, this is how the book represented it. http://imgur.com/a/vp8zQ

Comment: Are you comfortable you can "represent" your interpretations?

Comment: In a Posix shell, `a=b` does in fact assign the one character string "b" to the variable `a`, which suggests that someone did make that design decision. We could discuss whether or not it was a good decision, but that would have to be over a pair of virtual drinks, rather than on SO. :-)

Comment: @rici: As you have demonstrated by example, someone has *already* made that technical decision (esp. for the bad ones) for practically everything in the software space.   Virtual glass *clink* :-}

Comment: Yeah I understand it, just took an exam on it lets see how I do. Thanks.